# Ignore folder in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I organized the project in this way:
`/`This is my project root
`/JUICE/index.php`This is a page showing the projects and sends me a link to their folder
`/JUICE/.htaccess`
`/JUICE/projects/project01/index.php`
`/JUICE/projects/project02/index.php`
This is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=36288000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=36288000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that when the page `/JUICE/index.php` redirects on `/JUICE/projects/project01` folder with link like `<a href="projects/project01">link</a>`the server replies 404 without taking the `/JUICE/projects/project01/index.php`. If I call the direct link `/JUICE/projects/project01/index.php` everything works.

There is a way I can modify my .htaccess file to bypass the redirect rules in the "projects" folder?

Comment: Are your sure that it isn't your php application at fault? Rewrites don't alter the returned html.

Comment: @anubhava

There isn't .htaccess inside `/JUICE/projects/`.

@jedifans

The matter is actually much more complex, I tried to simplify it. If you want to see the original code is public and is located at this link: https://github.com/XaBerr/JUICE

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/JUICE/" />`, also `DirectoryIndex /index.php` should be `DirectoryIndex index.php`.

Comment: @anubhava 
I have that `<base href="/JUICE/">`, Link works good but htaccess redirect me in `index.php`. I don't want htaccess redirect me in `index.php` when I'm in this subfolder `/JUICE/projects`.

Comment: @anubhava
how do I check?
I think my server take `http://127.0.0.1/JUICE/projects/project01` do `R=301` and then redirect to `http://127/JUICE/index.php`

Comment: I thought I would add a condition like this:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projects/`
but I'm not a .htaccess expert, I do not know how to combine it without breaking things...

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^projects(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]` just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: @anubhava mmm in this computer works without problem, but in computer in my office doesn't... I need to try it on that computer when I get back from my business trip...